# VoIP Phone Reboot Leads to Internet Access?

Tags: networking, voip

So this isn't really an issue about not having access or anything but rather as to why this issue was resolved with the method I used.

So in the morning, I tried to connect to the internet but I couldn't access Outlook, Lync, Google.com, or anything else on the internet. The interesting thing was that I could make calls through My VoIP phone that is connected to the LAN and to my computer. Now when I reboot my phone by unplugging it from the internet and plugging it back in (the phone turns back on and good to go), I can now access Outlook, Lync, SAP, Google.com, and everything else.

Any ideas as to why this is happening because I'm just so confused.

Answer (score 2):

[image: VoIP Connection]

Usually a VoIP phone has two ethernet RJ-45 ports. One of them connects to the existing LAN using a cable that goes to the female RJ-45 on the wall, let's call it "**External**" and the other one using another cable that connects to your PC, that we are going to call "**Internal**".

The VoIP phone has an Ethernet switch inside, this switch allows the traffic coming from "**Internal**" to pass trought the phone and reach the "**External**" interface and the LAN. (In the image the LAN is represented as Catalyst Switch).

It seems that there was a problem with that internal switch, so it didn't allow the traffic coming from your PC to go throught the phone to reach the LAN. However the **External** side of your VoIP phone was still working, allowing you to make calls.

A reboot of the VoIP phone reset the internal switch, and your PC was able again to reach the LAN.

Comment: That's interesting, now what if the issue was also a problem for more than one user at my location? Would this now be related to the server?

Comment: If it happened to more than one user at the same time, it could be related to a problem in the LAN infrastructure. 
The internal switch of the VoIP phone is alwayas enabled no matter if the server is up or down. However, it could have matching parameters with the LAN equipment, (for example in the image it shows that the LAN have two VLANs (Virtual LANs)). If LAN failed and recovered during the night, it is possible that the internal switch inside the phone was unable to recover from that failure until it was rebooted.